# passing argument into jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm new to JS so please bear with me. I'm trying to pass a string parameter into a jQuery id selector but somehow it doesn't work..

HTML:

```
<li id="startPageButton" class="buttons" onclick="showContent(startPageContent, 394)">Startpage</li>
```

JS:

```
function showContent(cont, boxHeight) {
$(".content").fadeOut(5, function(){
    $("#contentBox").animate({height: boxHeight + "px" }, 400, function(){
        $("#" + cont).fadeIn(100);
    });
});
```

}

There's something wrong with the "$("#" + cont)" part.. if I replace that with a simple id selector it works :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace your code `onclick` attribute from this:

```
onclick="showContent(startPageContent, 394)"
```

to this:

```
onclick="showContent('startPageContent', 394)"
```

and try again..